# has_many through create joint table with attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-6

In my Rails app there are 3 model:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :roles
  has_many :companies, through: :roles
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :roles
  has_many :people, through: :roles
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :company
end
```

In console I'm able to create a joint table (Roles) with person_id and company_id, however I as well have job_title field I want to pass value during creation.

That's how I create joint table:

```
person = Person.find(id)
person.companies.create(legal_name: "Company name Ltd.")
```

As a result I get:

```
#<Role id: 1, person_id: 2, company_id: 25, job_title: nil>
```

Job title is nil and I want to populate this attribute with data during creation.

How I do something like this?

```
person = Person.find(id)
person.companies.create(legal_name: "Company name Ltd.", roles: [job_title: "Job title"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating instance of `Company` so you can set attributes of `Company` only via `create`.

`person.companies.create` will create instance of `Company`. Assign it to a local variable `company` and using `company` and `person` objects you can find role and update it's attribute

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction.do
  person = Person.find(id)
  person.companies.create!(legal_name: "Company name Ltd.")

  role = person.roles.find_by!(person: person, company: company
  role.update!(job_title: 'Manager')
end
```

Using transaction with bang `!` version method will ensure that the integrity of records.

**EDIT**

***What if there is validation on attributes on the joining model?***

Don't save the company record but just `build` it and use the new instance while creating role.

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction.do
  person = Person.find(id)
  company = person.companies.build(legal_name: "Company name Ltd.")
  person.roles.create!(job_title: 'Manager', company: company)
end
```

Comment: @Amil Patel what if I have job_title validation presence :true? Would give me error.